# Can't start apache2. "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

Tags: server, apache2

I also get this:
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.

After running it I got this:

```
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud apachectl[26565]: The Apache error log may have more information.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26540 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26541 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26540 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26541 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 26540 (apache2) remains running after unit stopped.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 26541 (apache2) remains running after unit stopped.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4128 and the job result is failed.
lines 2390-2418/2418 (END)
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud apachectl[26565]: The Apache error log may have more information.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26540 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26541 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26540 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26541 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 26540 (apache2) remains running after unit stopped.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 26541 (apache2) remains running after unit stopped.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4128 and the job result is failed.
```

And this for systemctl status apache2.service:

```
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-01-27 16:26:55 UTC; 2min 6s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 26565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9198)
     Memory: 57.6M
        CPU: 22ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─26540 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─26541 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud apachectl[26565]: The Apache error log may have more information.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26540 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26541 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26540 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 26541 (apache2) with signal SIGKILL.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 26540 (apache2) remains running after unit stopped.
ene 27 16:26:55 homecloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 26541 (apache2) remains running after unit stopped.
```

I already reinstalled apache, but this keeps happening

EDIT: Add log segment from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:00.609954 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26097] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:00.653672 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26097] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:00.653689 2023] [core:notice] [pid 26097] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:55.393099 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26097] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully –
```

Comment: Is there an Apache error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and does it provide any insight?

Comment: @DougSmythies There is a log, but don't really see anything that looks relevant
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:00.609954 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26097] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:00.653672 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26097] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
(continues next comment)

Comment: [Fri Jan 27 16:26:00.653689 2023] [core:notice] [pid 26097] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 27 16:26:55.393099 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26097] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

Comment: It is not obvious to me why `SIGWINCH` (resizing of a window) would result in a graceful shutdown.

Comment: @DougSmythies I'm trying to restart apache2, I run systemctl restart apache2, or stop and then start, but it doesn't work (stopping doesn't even stop it), but maybe what's causing issues is that?

Comment: Try increasing the error log level in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. By default it is `LogLevel warn`, so try `LogLevel debug`. Remember to revert afterwards, as `debug` logs a lot of stuff.